# Fortify security finding -- CWE 22 Path Manipulation

Tags: java, fortify

I have the below code to get the lastest modified file by given directory and the prefix of the filename.
When I ran the HPE fortify analysis it gave me "Path manipulation" findings.
Can you guys guide me how to fix this finding?
What is the best and secure approach to access filesystem for a web application?

```
public static File getLatestFilefromDirWithFileName(String archivesDirectoryPath, String fileStartWith){    
    File archivesDirectory = new File(archivesDirectoryPath);

    FilenameFilter textFilter = new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            if (name.startsWith(fileStartWith)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    };

    File[] filesInArchiveDir = archivesDirectory.listFiles(textFilter);
    if (filesInArchiveDir == null || filesInArchiveDir.length == 0) {
        return null;
    }

    File lastModifiedFile = filesInArchiveDir[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < filesInArchiveDir.length; i++) {
       if (lastModifiedFile.lastModified() < filesInArchiveDir[i].lastModified()) {
           lastModifiedFile = filesInArchiveDir[i];
       }
    }

    return lastModifiedFile;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must ensure that `archivesDirectoryPath` do not allow to access sensible folders.

One way to do it, is to validate that the specified folder will be located in a white list of location. This white list could either be define in your code or configurable by "administrator" users. Trying to process a folder that is not on this list should raise Exception.

You can check that no `/../` are used in folder name, but checking that the resulting folder is part of your white list should be enough.

Comment: I tried to create an enum to provide the whitelist but the fortify still complain my code of the same issue.

Comment: Fortify is a static analysis tool, and as such is not able to check your validation code. Now, that you have protected your application with a white list, you can mark this Fortify issue as a false positive.